# Is it possible to emulate a full (mifare 1k) card with the ChameleonMini (Rev.G 2)?

Tags: rfid, nfc

I am testing a lock box I own, it uses a Mifare 1k lock with default key, and I use a keyfob to unlock it.

I have both a Proxmark3 and a ChameleonMini.

With the Proxmark3 I am able to both clone the keyfob to a 'Chinese Magic' mifare 1k card and open the box with it, as well as emulate the card with the proxmark3 and open the box.

I have figured out using the Mifare1k sniffer ChameleonMini function to pull keys from the reader itself.

However, with the ChameleonMini, I seem to only be able to clone the UID, and read the data with the keys? When I emulate the card, it only gives the UID, I can't find a way to replay the entire card like the proxmark does....

While the emulated card does scan (the UID) with the NFC reader on my phone, the lock box doesn't respond to the ChameleonMini what-so-ever.

is it even possible to emulate the full card with the ChameleonMini? Or only the UID?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, custom firmware does support loading encrypted MIFARE Classic 1K images onto the Chameleon Mini. See https://github.com/maxieds/ChameleonCryptoModFirmware for detailed instructions.